# n-grams textbook question

Tags: natural-language-processing

I have this question I found regarding n-gram modeling in the *Speech and Language Processing* textbook by Daniel Jurafsky:

> Suppose we didn’t use the end-symbol `</s>`. Train an unsmoothed bigram grammar on the following training corpus without using the end-symbol `</s>`:
>   `<s>` a b
>   `<s>` b b
>   `<s>` b a
>   `<s>` a a
>   Demonstrate that your bigram model does not assign a single probability distribution across all sentence lengths by showing that the sum of the probability of the four possible 2-word sentences over the alphabet
>   {a,b} is 1.0, and the sum of the probability of all possible 3 word sentences over the alphabet {a,b} is also 1.0.

Please can you verify that is my approach correct?

Comment: @D.W.♦ Please can you help?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how to interpret $P\{x_1|x_2, x_3\}$, especially when I think you are assuming a probability of $0/1$ = 0 (what makes you do so?).

Comment: I don't see an approach.  We don't grade answers or check whether they're correct; that's not the purpose of this site.  Also, we discourage "here is my exercise problem, how do I solve it?" style questions.